# Puppet and systemctl trouble

Tags: puppet, centos7, hiera, systemctl

I have some trouble with puppet and systemctl. I used to load several parameters for a 'service' but it's not working anymore on centos7.

This is my error:

```
Error: Could not enable [ntpd ntpdate]: 
Error: /Stage[main]/Ntp::Service/Service[[ntpd ntpdate]]/enable: change from false to true failed: Could not enable [ntpd ntpdate]:
```

And this is my code :

Hiera :

```
ntp::service::ntp_services: 
  - "ntpd"
  - "ntpdate"
```

Service.pp :

```
class ntp::service ($ntp_services) {
    service {"$ntp_services":
        hasrestart  => false,
        hasstatus   => true,
        ensure      => running,
        enable      => true,
    }
}
```

It's working very well on centos 6 and it used to work on centos 7.

It works if I define the parameter like that :

```
ntp::service::ntp_services: "ntpd"
```

But I will have to define 1 parameter for 1 service...

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quotes on this line are likely to be causing the problem:

```
service {"$ntp_services":
```

Using `""` containing a variable will create a string with the variable expanded *inside* it. This is probably why Puppet is reporting a single service with the name `[ntpd ntpdate]` (i.e. an array) rather than two different services.

Change it to:

```
service { $ntp_services:
```

and this should pass the original array, generating one resource per item.